# Unable to log messages in console using Log4j2 but they get logged in the file

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

So I am trying to log the info and error messages to both the console and the log file. 
The messages get saved successfully in the log file but do not get logged in the console. Have attached the xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
        <Properties>
            <Property name="basePath">./DemoLogs</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/app.log" filePattern="${basePath}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %c{2} -%msg%n"/>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 KB"/>
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
            <Console name="Console">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="all">
                <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
            </Root>
            <Logger name="Demo" level="debug" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
            </Logger>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the console appender.

```
   <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
   </Root>
```